# app can't find module?

Tags: yii, module

I am working on a project. It was fine until I installed new windows on my PC. But now project is same and when I access

```
Yii::app()->controller->module
```

It returns `null`. It also returns `null` for: `Yii::app()->controller->module->id`. When I viewed config file it had admin module in it. I don't know why is it's returning `null`. Can't find a way out.
Module in config file is like:

```
'modules' => array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool
    'admin',
        'gii' => array(
             'generatorPaths' => array(
                'bootstrap.gii'
            ),
            'class' => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password' => '1234',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters' => array('127.0.0.1', '::1'),
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

When you access Yii::app()->controller->module then it will return the module that current controller belongs to. `It returns null if the controller does not belong to any module.` Please make sure the current controller  you accessed which is belong to any module you configured.

You can see this link: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module to work with Module.

If you want to see which modules are loaded then use:

```
print_r(Yii::app()->getModules());
```

You are not 'in' a module and want to get a specific module (like admin module): you can do

```
Yii::app()->getModule('admin');
```

Comment: how to register module to a controller? should i use "'admin'=>array(
            'defaultController'=>'/site'
        )," in module?

Comment: @jailed abroad: should i use "'admin'=>array( 'defaultController'=>'/site' )," in module? You do not need to do that. BTW, I updated my answer, please have a look at it!